Connection between Young diagram and highest weight of a representation of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$.
Given an irreducible representation of the group $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ corresponding to a Young diagram with $n$ rows with  $k_1 \geq \dots \geq k_n\geq 0$ cells respectively. How to recover its highest weight $(\lambda_1\geq \dots \geq \lambda_n)$?
(Guess: $\lambda_i=k_i$.)
Sorry if the question is too basic.

Your guess is good

Thanks. Do you have a reference?
